# while using @param tag parameter is printed twice when i move mouse over method name

Tags: java, javadoc

I have below method in my java class (classname: MyClass)

```
/**********************************    
*@param Request request
*@return Response
**********************************/
    Response myMethod(Request request ) throws Exception
```

when i move mouse over method name it shows like below

> **Response MyClass.myMethod(Request request) throws Exception**
>
> **Parameters:**

**Request** request

**request**

> **Returns:** Response
>
> **Throws: Exception**

I am not unble to understand why request parameter is printed twice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally don't include the type in @param javadocs.  It might just be printing it twice because it sees it twice.  It's usually more like:

```
@param request - this is my blah blah blah...
```

The javadoc generator will know the type already from inspecting the code.

(edited to give a specific example)

```
/**********************************    
*@param request - this is the request
*@return Response
**********************************/
Response myMethod(Request request ) throws Exception
```

Comment: if u dont include @param u wont see Parameters: in javadoc

Comment: You should include @param, and include the argument name, everything after that is the description.  You don't need to include the argument type (Request in your example).

Comment: also i have edited question as it is shown when i move over method name.